# Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Unified API

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

My service app works well with Office 365 Rest api: get access token, get all the data of all the users in my organization. Then, i try to use Office 365 Unified API. I've got access token but could not get data, always error "403 forbidden". Please give me some advice!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 Unified API doesn't yet support client credential flow.  Stay tuned, as we are working actively to add support.

Answer (score 0):

Client credential flow is now working as of last week (5 Nov 2015). Certainly using certificates for authentication.

Wasn't working a couple of weeks ago, so it must have been newly enabled.